# How do i add a button in an Actioncolumn in extjs

Tags: button, extjs, grid, handler

I hope this is my last question of today. I found a nice actioncolumn option in designer 2. I add one to my grid and it looks like this:

```
  xtype: 'gridpanel',
                        title: 'Reports',
                        forceFit: true,
                        store: 'ReportsStore',
                        columns: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Name',
                                text: 'Name'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Type',
                                text: 'Type'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Description',
                                text: 'Description'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Name',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e) {
                                            console.log(row, col);
                                        },
                                        altText: 'Run report',
                                        iconCls: 'runReport'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        viewConfig: {

                        },
                        dockedItems: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'toolbar',
                                dock: 'top',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'tbfill'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        iconCls: 'addReport',
                                        text: 'Add report',
                                        listeners: {
                                            click: {
                                                fn: me.onButtonClick,
                                                scope: me
                                            }
```

But there is nothing happening. What i want is that there is an button/icon and when you click on it it will open a ext.window with the reportId from that row. I can't find how i do this with designer.

I don't see an icon now so there is nothing yet to click on. What do i miss?

Thanks,

TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss listener for this button:

add something like that into your item definition:

```
handler: function(grid, row, col) {
   console.log(row, col);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i added this to my code but it is still an empty column. I edited my code with more details. Could you tell what i miss?

Comment: you don't see an icon? Add "icon: 'somefile.png'" property. and change console.log to print out proper parameters